# How do I get a shape to loop across the screen in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

```
    import pygame
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1600,900))
    red=(255,0,0)
    blue=(0,0,204)
    white=(255,255,255)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Orbit")
    gameLoop=True 
    clock=pygame.time.Clock()
    while gameLoop:

      dy=10 
      dx=10
      x=600
      y=250



      for event in pygame.event.get():

          if (event.type==pygame.QUIT):
           gameLoop=False
      x=x +dx 
      y=y +dy

     screen.fill(white)
     pygame.draw.circle(screen,red,[800,450],50,0)
     pygame.draw.circle(screen,blue,[x,y],10,0)
     pygame.display.update()
     clock.tick(50)
    pygame.quit()
```

I wrote this code here that has two circles and I want to get one (the smaller one) to loop across the screen but for some reason its not moving, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong and I've read and googled some stuff that hasn't really helped me all that much.Any advice would be greatly appreciated , thank you for your time

Comment: also if this helps to know im using the sublime IDE with python 3.6.4

Comment: You should fix those indentations...

Comment: Please read [this guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) on how to format your code blocks. It makes it much easier for us to detect your error when your code is correctly indented.

Answer (score 2):

Your `x` and `y` values are defined inside your game loop, and so even though you're adding `dx` and `dy` to them, you're resetting them to the original values every frame.

If you move `x=600` and `y=250` to before the while loop, it'll start moving.